# ReactJS / Typescript / Redux - onChange event with datatype number and comma values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, redux

the following situation:
I have a reactjs/redux/typescript application.

I have a two way binding with redux for my input textboxes with the onChange event. The props are all declared with the datatype "number". Everything works as expected.

The only problem i have is when i want to type in comma seperated values i cannot store it as number in my redux store. It seems that it will store it as string and not as number but i want to store it as number.

My input box looks like this:

```js
<input
value={props.number || ""}
onChange={e => props.updateValue({ number: +e.target.value })}
/>
```

with the `+e.target.value` i convert the string value from the input field to a number, because i expect a number and nothing else. But i want also that ive been able to put in a comma seperated value.

The problem is that because of the onChange event the comma value cannot be stored because when i try to type in for example "1.1" on the second character "1." this is not a number.

**For better understanding i created a codesandbox example:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-with-typescript-xt2tc?fontsize=14

My question: What is the best/smartest way to handle this situation? I dont want to store the values as String, because it is not a string.

Thanks in advance for your help and for all ideas.

Comment: I modified a little to make things work, please check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-with-typescript-6q1fz

Comment: The input could be empty now, but the thing is, when it's empty, the value must be type string; I think it's reasonable because no Number can be represented as empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the [`<input type="number" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number), it's also better for UX and makes more sense semantically.

```
  <input
    type="number"
    value={props.number || ""}
    onChange={e => props.updateValue({ number: +e.target.value })}
  />
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-with-typescript-bu305

Comment: I recognized a new behavior with this. I cannot clear the input field completly...i think because it is a number field. Is it possible to clear it completly? Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-with-typescript-h13t5?fontsize=14

Comment: @Hannes Try changing `number: +e.target.value` to `number: e.target.value`, it should already be a number because of the input type.

Comment: `number: appState.number === 0 ? undefined : appState.number,` giving `undefined` seems making the input clearable @Hannes

Comment: `state: AppState = { number: "1" },` this should be `number: 1` and `state.number = "1";` should be removed, just `return state`, that's how redux state initialization work

Comment: Wont work...i must be able to type in a 0, too. Remove the plus for the converting to int will work but the number will again be stored as string then.

Comment: @Hannes Are you sure it's stored as string and not as number?

Comment: Yes 100%. I solved it with the inspiration of @MarsonMao 's Example. Thanks